# Navigation Drawer listview not refreshing listitems

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, visibility

I am creating one app,and i am using `NavigationDrawer` and `Fragments` in my application,now issue is I have five `ListItems` in `NavigationDrawer` like this.

-Home
-Edit Profile
-My orders
-Signout
-Help

Now when user click on signout,all the listitems should hide and only signin should visible..

following is my snippet code

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String abc;
private Intent ii;
// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;
// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ii=getIntent();


    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);



    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();



    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    //navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);

        if(position == 4) { // position of Sign out button

            navDrawerItems.clear(); // empty the adapter array

            navMenuIcons.recycle();

            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

            //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[signoutIndex], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(signoutIndex, -1));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
        else
        {
            if(ii.hasExtra("login"))
            {
                abc=ii.getStringExtra("login");

                if(abc.equals("login"))
                {
                    navDrawerItems.clear();
                    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
                    // Find People
                    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
                    // Photos
                    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
                    // Communities, Will add a counter here
                    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
                    // Pages
                    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"success"+abc,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"unsuccess"+abc,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:


        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:


        fragment = new LoginActivity();
        break;
    case 5:

            fragment = new LoginActivity();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}



@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}
LoginActivity.java

```
    public class LoginActivity extends Fragment{

public LoginActivity(){}

private Button alreadymember;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_activity, container, false);

    alreadymember=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_login_alredymember);

    alreadymember.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            HomeFragment tf = new HomeFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Accepted answer not working?

Comment: its working but right now issue is..when i click on signin it shows view of editprofile..

Comment: And edit profile view is in List Items?

Comment: no its not..only home and signin shows..

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't try to hide the drawer items. I would just update the adapter, remove the items you don't need and then invalidate it.

When the user clicks on `Signout`, I would just do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // display view for selected nav drawer item
    displayView(position);

    // if using fixed positions
    if(position == 6) { // position of Sign out button

        navDrawerItems.clear(); // empty the adapter array
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[signoutIndex], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(signoutIndex, -1));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: When user logs out, I would just do `navDrawerItems.clear()` to empty the adapter array, then add the sign out NavDrawerItem to it. After that call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I don't understand the changed question, I would still solve it like I wrote :)

Comment: Hmm, not sure, try debugging it, and go step by step to see if your `getIcon()` method returns anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79489/discussion-between-roman-and-vedran-kopanja).

Comment: same issue can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683232/how-to-refresh-navigation-drawer

Comment: instead of list, how to refresh navigation's user profile image