# My circular imageview not working properly

Tags: android, android-imageview

I follow this example [here][1] to to give circuler shape. I am getting images from server and set it via `BaseAdapter`, the image is showing but not in circular view. So, can anyone tell what is the mistake with my code, following is the way I load the images and set circular shape

```
aQuery.id(holder.propic).image(listData.get(position).get(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMG),true,true,0,R.drawable.ic_launcher);


Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listData.get(position).get(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMG));

holder.propic.setImageBitmap(icon);
```

Comment: show your xml where u created circular imageview..

Comment: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: @HarishVats its same imageview like given in example

Comment: @Aditya I can't find the link to the example you refering.

Comment: Aditya can you just try with a static image just for testing. take image from drawable. then I can try more to help you.

Comment: yes with static it works fine

Comment: Okay.. When you are converting your image from to bitmap, are you sure that your image has been already downloaded ?

Comment: yes it is downloaded..

Comment: mate your stacktrace says that you have exception on line 38 in RoundImageView class. There must be something which is passed with null value. please look into that by enable debugging mode into your IDE.

Comment: @NarendraPal  Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);/this is my 38 line

Comment: @Aditya Please provide onDraw() code with line number 38 as highlight. You are getting nullpointer getting on at com.pattaniinfotech.rajpootbook.RoundedImageView.onDraw(RoundedImageView.java:38) Or double click on this line in logcate you will be getting selected line

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
see my question

Comment: @Pratik any iddea???

Comment: @Aditya can you point out line number 38 in your code? it would be easy for me to know where you getting nullpointer exact

Comment: @Pratik can you tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this link for library to get circular image view
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();

    private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private int mBitmapWidth;
    private int mBitmapHeight;

    private float mDrawableRadius;
    private float mBorderRadius;

    private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

    private boolean mReady;
    private boolean mSetupPending;
    private boolean mBorderOverlay;

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

        mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
        mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
        mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);

        a.recycle();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
        mReady = true;

        if (mSetupPending) {
            setup();
            mSetupPending = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return SCALE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        if (adjustViewBounds) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (getDrawable() == null) {
            return;
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
        if (mBorderWidth != 0) {
            canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setup();
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
        if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderColor = borderColor;
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColorResource(@ColorRes int borderColorRes) {
        setBorderColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(borderColorRes));
    }

    public int getBorderWidth() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
        setup();
    }

    public boolean isBorderOverlay() {
        return mBorderOverlay;
    }

    public void setBorderOverlay(boolean borderOverlay) {
        if (borderOverlay == mBorderOverlay) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderOverlay = borderOverlay;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        mBitmap = bm;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
        super.setImageURI(uri);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (cf == mColorFilter) {
            return;
        }

        mColorFilter = cf;
        mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
        invalidate();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
            } else {
                bitmap = Bitmap
                        .createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setup() {
        if (!mReady) {
            mSetupPending = true;
            return;
        }

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

        mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2);

        mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
        if (!mBorderOverlay) {
            mDrawableRect.inset(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth);
        }
        mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2, mDrawableRect.width() / 2);

        updateShaderMatrix();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void updateShaderMatrix() {
        float scale;
        float dx = 0;
        float dy = 0;

        mShaderMatrix.set(null);

        if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
            scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
            dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
        } else {
            scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
            dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
        }

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.left, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.top);

        mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
    }

}
```

And use it in your containt_activity.xml like this:

```
<com.example.customewidget.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgUserImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image_available"
            app:border_color="@color/white"
            app:border_width="1dp" />
```

Add in you Activity or Fragment class:

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
    private CircleImageView imgUserImage;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.containt_activity);

    imgUserImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgUserImage);
    //here set your image view
}
```

Comment: i am downloading image then set it..so thats the issue my friend\

Comment: i tried with picasso too..but can you tell just how to set?

Comment: Hi Aditya you can use Picasso lib. and use below code for set image.
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url) .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image_available)     .into(imgUserImage);